# Why isn't this this applicative statement being lazily evaluated, and how can I understand why?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, applicative, io-monad

```
abc :: IO (Int)
abc = do
  print "abc"
  pure $ 10

xyz :: IO (Int)
xyz = undefined

main :: IO () 
main = do
  x <- (((+) <$> abc <*> abc) <* xyz)
  print x
```

Why in the above is `xyz` being evaluated? I would assume due to Haskell's lazy nature it would not need to evaluate `xyz` (and hence not reach the `undefined`)?

My assumption is based on the type of `<*`:

```
Prelude> :t (<*)
(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a
```

Following on with:

```
    -- | Sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument.
    (*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
    a1 *> a2 = (id <$ a1) <*> a2
```

And:

```
(<$)        :: a -> f b -> f a
(<$)        =  fmap . const
```

And hence `f b` never gets used.

---

**Is there a way I can understand / investigate why this is being evaluated strictly? Would looking at the GHC compiled Core be helpful in this?**

---

Thanks to the discussion in the comments it seems (please someone correct me if I'm wrong) it's due to the `Monad` implementation of the `IO` because the following two statements seem to evaluate differently:

Identity:

```
runIdentity $ const <$> (pure 1 :: Identity Int) <*> undefined
1
```

IO:

```
const <$> (pure 1 :: IO Int) <*> undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Comment: `(<*)` doesn't use the `b` values from the `f b`, but it does use the `f` effects (for instance, using `\x -> return x <* print x` will actually print `x`), so it must inspect the second argument.

Comment: How/why is it used though? What is responsible for this?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski The runtime system executes `main`, and is responsible for discovering all the `IO` effects reachable from it.

Comment: This doesn't happen just with `IO`, either. For instance, while `Just 1 <* Just 2` is `Just 1`,  `Just 1 <* Nothing` is `Nothing`. There is no way to figure that out without inspecting the second argument.

Comment: Imagine if one wrote `putStrLn "Hello!" *> putStrLn "World!"`. What would the output be?

Comment: Oh that is a good example. Why does that execute both while `const (print "test") (print "test2")` does not?

Comment: Okay so that narrows it down even further to: `fmap (const) (putStrLn "test")` printing `test`... Which I suppose comes down to the implementation of the IO Monad?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski "Which I suppose comes down to the implementation of the IO Monad?" -- Yup, pretty much so.

Comment: consider `const <$> Just 1 <*> Just undefined`, `const <$> Just 1 <*> undefined`, `runIdentity $ const <$> Identity 1 <*> undefined` (you might need to `import Data.Functor.Identity` for the last one). So yes, it's in the definition of the applicative instance for the particular functor. (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467803/how-to-handle-side-effect-with-applicative/24467994#24467994)

Comment: `xyz = pure undefined` will do what you expect—`<*` is (for most applicatives) strict in the effects, but it’s non-strict in the right operand’s *result*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(<*)` doesn't use the `b` values from the `f b`, but it does use the `f` effects, so it must inspect the second argument.

> Why does [`putStrLn "Hello!" *> putStrLn "World!"`] execute both while `const (print "test") (print "test2")` does not?

In the type of `const`...

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

... both `a` and `b` are fully parametric, and there is nothing else to deal with. With `(<*)`, though, the situation is rather different. For starters, `(<*)` is a method of `Applicative`, so anyone writing [an `Applicative` instance for `IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1353) can supply a concrete...

```
(<*) :: IO a -> IO b -> IO a
```

... implementation that uses `IO`-specific functions to combine effects from the two arguments in whatever way is deemed necessary.

Furthermore, even if `(<*)` weren't a method of `Applicative`, its type...

```
(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a
```

... is such that, though `a` and `b` are fully parametric, `f` is not, because of the `Applicative` constraint. Its implementation can use other methods of `Applicative`, which can, and in most cases will, use the effects from both arguments.

Note that this is not an `IO`-specific issue. For instance, here is `(<*) @Maybe` not ignoring the effects of its second argument:

```
GHCi> Just 1 <* Just 2
Just 1
GHCi> Just 1 <* Nothing
Nothing
```