# Confused about GADTs and propagating constraints

Tags: haskell, gadt

There's plenty of Q&A about `GADTs` being better than `DatatypeContexts`, because GADTs automagically make constraints available in the right places. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465586/why-constraints-on-data-are-a-bad-thing), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770278/typeclass-constraints-on-data-declarations), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927710/type-constraints-for-automatic-function-constraint-deduction-in-haskell). But sometimes it seems I still need an explicit constraint. What's going on? Example adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24466703/2840542):

```
{-# LANGUAGE  GADTs  #-}
import Data.Maybe                                              -- fromJust

data GADTBag a  where
  MkGADTBag :: Eq a => { unGADTBag :: [a] } -> GADTBag a

baz (MkGADTBag x) (Just y) = x == y

baz2           x        y  = unGADTBag x == fromJust y


-- unGADTBag :: GADTBag a -> [a]                               -- inferred, no Eq a

-- baz ::          GADTBag a -> Maybe [a] -> Bool              -- inferred, no Eq a
-- baz2 :: Eq a => GADTBag a -> Maybe [a] -> Bool              -- inferred, with Eq a
```

Why can't the type for `unGADTBag` tell us `Eq a`?

`baz` and `baz2` are morally equivalent, yet have different types. Presumably because `unGADTBag` has no `Eq a`, then the constraint can't propagate into any code using `unGADTBag`.

But with `baz2` there's an `Eq a` constraint hiding inside the `GADTBag a`. Presumably `baz2`'s `Eq a` will want a duplicate of the dictionary already there(?)

Is it that potentially a GADT might have many data constructors, each with different (or no) constraints? That's not the case here, or with typical examples for constrained data structures like Bags, Sets, Ordered Lists.

The equivalent for a `GADTBag` datatype using `DatatypeContexts` infers `baz`'s type same as `baz2`.

Bonus question: why can't I get an ordinary `... deriving (Eq)` for `GADTBag`? I can get one with `StandaloneDeriving`, but it's blimmin obvious, why can't GHC just do it for me?

```
deriving instance (Eq a) => Eq (GADTBag a)
```

Is the problem again that there might be other data constructors?

(Code exercised at GHC 8.6.5, if that's relevant.)

**Addit:** in light of @chi's and @leftroundabout's answers -- neither of which I find convincing. All of these give `*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`:

```
*DTContexts> unGADTBag undefined
*DTContexts> unGADTBag $ MkGADTBag undefined
*DTContexts> unGADTBag $ MkGADTBag (undefined :: String)
*DTContexts> unGADTBag $ MkGADTBag (undefined :: [a])

*DTContexts> baz undefined (Just "hello")
*DTContexts> baz (MkGADTBag undefined) (Just "hello")
*DTContexts> baz (MkGADTBag (undefined :: String)) (Just "hello")

*DTContexts> baz2 undefined (Just "hello")
*DTContexts> baz2 (MkGADTBag undefined) (Just "hello")
*DTContexts> baz2 (MkGADTBag (undefined :: String)) (Just "hello")
```

Whereas these two give the same type error at compile time <s>``` * Couldn't match expected type ``[Char]' ```</s>``` * No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of ``MkGADTBag' ```/ ``` ``baz2' ``` respectively [**Edit:** my initial Addit gave the wrong expression and wrong error message]:

```
*DTContexts> baz (MkGADTBag (undefined :: [Int -> Int])) (Just [(+ 1)])
*DTContexts> baz2 (MkGADTBag (undefined :: [Int -> Int])) (Just [(+ 1)])
```

So `baz, baz2` are morally equivalent not just in that they return the same result for the same well-defined arguments; but also in that they exhibit the same behaviour for the same ill-defined arguments. Or they differ only in where the absence of an `Eq` instance gets reported?

> @leftroundabout Before you've actually deconstructed the `x` value, there's no way of knowing that the `MkGADTBag` constructor indeed applies.

Yes there is: field label `unGADTBag` is defined if and only if there's a pattern match on `MkGADTBag`. (It would maybe be different if there were other constructors for the type -- especially if those also had a label `unGADTBag`.) Again, being undefined/lazy evaluation doesn't postpone the type-inference.

To be clear, by "[not] convincing" I mean: I can see the behaviour and the inferred types I'm getting. I don't see that laziness or potential undefinedness gets in the way of type inference. How could I expose a difference between `baz, baz2` that would explain why they have different types?

Comment: For `quux x = const x (x == x)` GHC infers `quux :: Eq a => a -> a`. `unGADTBag` demands `MkGADTBag` demands `Eq a` in the same way as `quux`, whether or not any equality test is evaluated or `Eq` dictionary is applied. Then why does `unGADTBag` lose the `Eq a`?

Answer (score 5):

Function calls never bring type class constraints in scope, only (strict) pattern matching does.

The comparison

```
unGADTBag x == fromJust y
```

is essentially a function call of the form

```
foo (unGADTBag x) (fromJust y)
```

where `foo` requires `Eq a`. That would morally be provided by `unGADTBag x`, but that expression is not yet evaluated! Because of laziness, `unGADTBag x` will be evaluated only when (and if) `foo` demands its first argument.

So, in order to call `foo` in this example we need its argument to be evaluated in advance. While Haskell could work like this, it would be a rather surprising semantics, where arguments are evaluated or not depending on whether they provide a type class constraint which is needed. Imagine more general cases like

```
foo (if cond then unGADTBag x else unGADTBag z) (fromJust y)
```

What should be evaluated here? `unGADTBag x`? `unGADTBag y`? Both? `cond` as well? It's hard to tell.

Because of these issues, Haskell was designed so that we need to manually require the evaluation of a GADT value like `x` using pattern matching.

Comment: The question is about type inference -- or isn't it? So how could laziness/timing of evaluation have a bearing on the typing, which happens at compile time? We don't need to evaluate `x` or `unGADTBag x` to know there's a constraint inside(?)

Comment: @AntC We do need to evaluate that. Consider the definition `x = x :: GADTBag (Int->Int)` which uses infinite recursion. This type checks, but there's no dictionary inside `x` for the constraint `Eq (Int -> Int)` (indeed, it would even be impossible to construct such dictionary). We can't call `==` unless we evaluate `x` first and extract the dictionary inside. In a strict (non lazy language), any variable `x` with type `GADTBag (Int->Int)` would surely carry the dictionary, but in a lazy language it can involve non-termination and fail to provide that.

Comment: The call to `foo` needs `Eq`. The call to `foo` happens _before_ the call to `unGADTBag`. Therefore, `Eq` for `foo` cannot come from the result of `unGADTBag`. Therefore, it needs to come from the context. Therefore, that's the type you get.

Comment: @AntC About the compile time aspects: it's true that typing is compile time, but typing must guarantee that code generation (= compilation to assembly) is possible in a way that respects the semantics. To make this possible, the semantics must require evaluating `unGADTBag x` if its dictionary is required, which is very tricky to work with. In your type any (already evaluated) value of type `GADTBag a` is implemented as a pair: the `Eq a` dictionary, and the `[a]` value. We need to use the first component to call `==` on `a`, so we must start by evaluating that `GADTBag a` value first.

Comment: @AntC That semantics is really ugly, so Haskell does not use that, but requires that the programmer uses pattern matching so to make the evaluation order more explicit, allowing the compiler to extract the dictionary in a user-predictable point. This requirement is done in the type system, which rejects your code as you noticed, since there would be no way to proceed with assembly code generation later on.

Comment: Thanks. I think for the Bags/Sets/Ordered Lists use cases, I was hoping type inference could see the many places there's `Eq a` and float them all out to widest scope (of `a`), so the dictionary gets evaluated/demanded only once. `DatatypeContexts` at least puts the constraint at outermost scope of the datatype; and puts it on the type constructor not the data constructors; but does a poor job of recognising/scoping together all the places it's needed. I'm not seeing that GADTs with constraints answer all of the requirements that `DatatypeContexts` try (and fail) to meet.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't the type for `unGADTBag` tell us `Eq a`?

Before you've actually deconstructed the `x` value, there's no way of knowing that the `MkGADTBag` constructor indeed applies. Sure, if it doesn't then you have other problems (bottom), but those might conceivably not surface. Consider

```
ignore :: a -> b -> b
ignore _ = id

baz2' :: GADTBag a -> Maybe [a] -> Bool
baz2' x y = ignore (unGADTBag x) (y==y)
```

Note that I could now invoke the function with, say, `undefined :: GADTBag (Int->Int)`. Shouldn't be a problem since the `undefined` is `ignore`d, right<sup>★</sup>? Problem is, despite `Int->Int` not having an `Eq` instance, I was able to write `y==y`, which `y :: Maybe [Int->Int]` can't in fact support.

So, we can't have that only *mentioning* `unGADTBag` is enough to spew the `Eq a` constraint into its surrounding scope. Instead, we must clearly delimit the scope of that constraint to where we've confirmed that the `MkGADTBag` constructor *does* apply, and a pattern match accomplishes that.

---

<sup>★</sup><sub>If you're annoyed that my argument relies on `undefined`, note that the same issue arises also when there are multiple constructors which would bring different constraints into scope.</sub>

---

An alternative to a pattern-match that does work is this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

withGADTBag :: GADTBag a -> (Eq a => [a] -> b) -> b
withGADTBag (MkGADTBag x) f = f x

baz3 :: GADTBag a -> Maybe [a] -> Bool
baz3 x y = withGADTBag x (== fromJust y)
```

---

### Response to edits

> All of these give `*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`:

Yes of course they do, because you actually evaluate `x == y` in your function. So the function can only possibly yield non-`⟂` if the inputs have a NF. But that's by no means the case for all functions.

> Whereas these two give the same type error at compile time

Of course they do, because you're trying to wrap a value of non-`Eq` type in the `MkGADTBag` constructor, which explicitly requires that constraint (and allows you to explicitly unwrap it again!), whereas the `GADTBag` *type* doesn't require that constraint. (Which is kind of the whole point about this sort of encapsulation!)

> > Before you've actually deconstructed the x value, there's no way of knowing that the `MkGADTBag` constructor indeed applies.
>
> Yes there is: field label `unGADTBag` is defined if and only if there's a pattern match on `MkGADTBag`.

Arguably, that's the way field labels *should* work, but they don't, in Haskell. A field label is nothing but a function from the data type to the field type, and a *nontotal* function at that if there are multiple constructors.
Yeah, Haskell records are one of the worst-designed features of the language. I personally tend to use field labels only for big, single-constructor, plain-old-data types (and even then I prefer using not the field labels directly but [lenses](http://lens.github.io/) derived from them).

Anyway though, I don't see how “field label is defined iff there's a pattern match” could even be implemented in a way that would allow your code to work the way you think it should. The compiler would have to insert the step of confirming that the constructor applies (and extracting its GADT-encapsulated constraint) somewhere. But *where*? In your example it's reasonably obvious, but in general `x` could inhabit a vast scope with lots of decision branches and you really don't want it to get evaluated in a branch where the constraint isn't actually needed.

Also keep in mind that when we argue with `undefined`/`⟂` it's not just about actually diverging computations, more typically you're worried about computations that would simply take a long time (just, Haskell doesn't actually have a notion of “taking a long time”).

Comment: SPJ is on record (all over the place) as saying that `DatatypeContexts` are a mis-feature because they require evidence for a constraint in places you'd expect type inference to provide it. But that seems an excellent way to put what's going on with `baz2`'s inferred `Eq a`. "The whole point about this sort of encapsulation" is that for a Set/Bag type, I _want_ the constraint to propagate, not get encapsulated. So in this use-case, GADTs seem to be a mis-feature. (That is, mis-feature in a different way.)

Comment: Contrast that in the use-case of GADTs for richer typing of EDSLs, there's many constructors, each with different constraints/typing as you go down the syntax tree. A Set/Bag has the same content type/same constraint throughout the tree -- I'm assuming it's a Set represented as a binary balanced tree.

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about this is [OutsideIn(X) ... with local assumptions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/jfp-outsidein.pdf). It's not about undefinedness or lazy evaluation. A pattern match on a GADT constructor is outside, the RHS of the equation is inside. Constraints from the constructor are made available only locally -- that is only inside.

```
baz (MkGADTBag x) (Just y) = x == y
```

Has an explicit data constructor `MkGADTBag` outside, supplying an `Eq a`. The `x == y` raises a wanted `Eq a` locally/inside, which gets discharged from the pattern match. OTOH

```
baz2           x        y  = unGADTBag x == fromJust y
```

Has no explicit data constructor outside, so no context is supplied. `unGADTBag` has a `Eq a`, but that is deeper inside the l.h. argument to `==`; type inference doesn't go looking deeper inside. It just doesn't. Then in the effective definition for `unGADTBag`

```
unGADTBag (MkGADTBag x) = x
```

there is an `Eq a` made available from the outside, but it cannot escape from the RHS into the type environment at a usage site for `unGADTBag`. It just doesn't. Sad!

The best I can see for an explanation is towards the end of the OutsideIn paper, Section ***9.7 Is the emphasis on principal types well-justified?*** (A rhetorical question but my answer would me: of course we must emphasise principal types; type inference could get better principaled under some circumstances.) That last section considers this example

> ```
>     data R a where
>       RInt :: Int -> R Int
>       RBool :: Bool -> R Bool
>       RChar :: Char -> R Char
>
>     flop1 (RInt x) = x
> ```

> there is a third type that is arguably more desirable [for `flop1`], and that type is `R Int -> Int`.

`flop1`'s definition is of the same form as `unGADTBag`, with `a` constrained to be `Int`.

> ```
>     flop2 (RInt x) = x
>     flop2 (RBool x) = x
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, ordinary polymorphic types are too weak to express this restriction [that `a` must be only `Int` or `Bool`] and we can only get `Ɐa.R a -> a` for `flop2`, which does not rule the application of `flop2` to values of type `R Char`.

So at that point the paper seems to give up trying to refine better principal types:

> In conclusion, giving up on some natural principal types in favor of more specialized types that eliminate more pattern match errors at runtime is appealing but does not quite work unless we consider a more expressive syntax of types. Furthermore it is far from obvious how to *specify* these typings in a high-level declarative specification.

"is appealing". It just doesn't.

I can see a general solution is difficult/impossible. But for use-cases of constrained Bags/Lists/Sets, the specification is:

- All data constructors have the same constraint(s) on the datatype's parameters.
- All constructors yield the same type (`... -> T a` or `... -> T [a]` or `... -> T Int`, etc).
- Datatypes with a single constructor satisfy that trivially.

To satisfy the first bullet, for a Set type using a binary balanced tree, there'd be a non-obvious definition for the Nil constructor:

```
data OrdSet a  where
  SNode :: Ord a => OrdSet a -> a -> OrdSet a -> OrdSet a
  SNil  :: Ord a => OrdSet a                     -- seemingly redundant Ord constraint
```

Even so, repeating the constraint on every node and every terminal seems wasteful: it's the same constraint all the way down (which is unlike GADTs for EDSL abstract syntax trees); presumably each node carries a copy of exactly the same dictionary.

The best way to ensure same constraint(s) on every constructor could just be prefixing the constraint to the datatype:

```
data Ord a => OrdSet a  where ...
```

And perhaps the constraint could go 'OutsideOut' to the environment that's accessing the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to use a `PatternSynonym` with [an explicit signature giving a *Required* constraint](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typing-of-pattern-synonyms).

```
pattern EqGADTBag :: Eq a => [a] -> GADTBag a              -- that Eq a is the *Required*
pattern EqGADTBag{ unEqGADTBag } = MkGADTBag unEqGADTBag   -- without sig infers Eq a only as *Provided*
```

That is, without that explicit sig:

```
*> :i EqGADTBag
pattern EqGADTBag :: () => Eq a => [a] -> GADTBag a
```

The `() => Eq a => ...` shows `Eq a` is Provided, arising from the GADT constructor.

Now we get both inferred `baz, baz2 :: Eq a => GADTBag a -> Maybe [a] -> Bool`:

```
baz (EqGADTBag x) (Just y) = x == y

baz2           x        y  = unEqGADTBag x == fromJust y
```

As a curiosity: it's possible to give those equations for `baz, baz2` as well as those in the O.P. using the names from the GADT decl. GHC warns of overlapping patterns [correctly]; and does infer the constrained sig for `baz`.

I wonder if there's a design pattern here? Don't put constraints on the data constructor -- that is, don't make it a GADT. Instead declare a 'shadow' `PatternSynonym` with the Required/Provided constraints.

Comment: Don't make it a GADT? Then how will you define the pattern? `unsafeCoerce`?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't follow: what is there to coerce? I have a `GADTBag a`. If `Eq a` then the pattern succeeds (or rather function `baz` matching on it does); if not, compile fail. (By "Don't make it a GADT" I mean make it an ordinary H2010 datatype.) "Don't put constraints on the data constructor" mirrors the reasons for deprecating `DatatypeContexts`: you won't need those constraints everywhere; put them only where the consuming function needs them.

Comment: ah, well, it really depends on what you're doing, doesn't it? Yes, you should avoid bundling up dictionaries just for the heck of it, but sometimes it's the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the constraint in a fold function, `(Eq a => ..)` says you can assume `Eq a` but only within the function `next` (which is defined after a pattern match). If you instantiate `next as = fromJust maybe == as` it uses this constraint to witness equality

```
--              local constraint 
--              |
--              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
foldGADTBag :: (Eq a => [a] -> res) -> GADTBag a -> res
foldGADTBag next (MkGADTBag as) = next as

baz3 :: GADTBag a -> Maybe [a] -> Bool
baz3 gadtBag maybe = foldGADTBag (fromJust maybe ==) gadtBag
```

---

```
type Ty :: Type -> Type
data Ty a where
 TyInt  :: Int -> Ty Int
 TyUnit :: Ty ()

--         locally assume Int       locally assume unit
--         |                        |
--         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      vvvvvvvvvvvvv
foldTy :: (a ~ Int => a -> res) -> (a ~ () => res) -> (Ty a -> res)
foldTy int unit (TyInt i) = int i
foldTy int unit TyUnit    = unit

eval :: Ty a -> a
eval = foldTy id ()
```

Comment: Thanks (I think -- I'm struggling to drag this back from the memory banks after so many months). So this avoids needing constraints (or even specific types) inside the GADT -- making it an ordinary datatype. That'll work for the Bags/Sets I asked about. Your `data Ty a` example shows this doesn't scale to (for example) a GADT representing a EDSL: just too many types in the AST.

Comment: I know it's been a while since it was asked, I was looking for interesting questions :)